# Dynamics 365 FetchXML - Use IN operator for string

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml, xrmtoolbox

As I need to create a query where I need to add a filter condition where valid entitytype could be any from e1,e2,e3.

For that I have currently written below FetchXML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" top="5000">
  <entity name="changelog" >
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
      <condition attribute="event" operator="eq" value="Delete" />
      <filter type="or" >
        <condition attribute="entitytype" operator="eq" value="email" />
        <condition attribute="entitytype" operator="eq" value="fax" />
        <condition attribute="entitytype" operator="eq" value="letter" />
        <condition attribute="entitytype" operator="eq" value="phonecall" />
      </filter>
    </filter>
    <order attribute="statuscode" />
    <order attribute="event" />
    <order attribute="createdon" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Above query is passing the expected records.

But, I believe there could be another approach for this too - by using IN operator for the entitytype condition.

To test that query I am using XRMTool's [FetchXML Tester](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MscrmTools.FetchXmlTester/) which is throwing an error. The query is as below:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" top="5000">
  <entity name="changelog" >
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
      <condition attribute="event" operator="eq" value="Delete" />
            <condition attribute="entitytype" operator="in" >
                <value>
                    phonecall
                </value>
                <value>
                    email
                </value>
                <value>
                    fax
                </value>
                <value>
                    letter
                </value>
            </condition>
        </filter>
        <order attribute="statuscode" />
        <order attribute="event" />
        <order attribute="createdon" />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Above query is not returning any records as a result.

**Note**: I have formatted this using the FetchXML Testers' Format button.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was the default format option provided by [FetchXML Tester](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MscrmTools.FetchXmlTester/).

The way it was formatting the FetchXML was the reason it was not returning any value.

It is supposed to be formatted as below:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" top="5000">
  <entity name="changelog" >
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
      <condition attribute="event" operator="eq" value="Delete" />
            <condition attribute="entitytype" operator="in" >
                 <value>phonecall</value>
                 <value>email</value>
                 <value>fax</value>
                 <value>letter</value>
            </condition>
        </filter>
        <order attribute="statuscode" />
        <order attribute="event" />
        <order attribute="createdon" />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```